# Can't login to nexus docker private registry using Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nexus3

I'm trying to create a local docker private registry. I am following the [documentation](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/nexus-repository-administration/formats/docker-registry/docker-authentication).

For this purpose I have created the following docker-compose.yaml file in order to deploy the Nexus web UI (8081) and expose `5000` port for docker private repository.

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  nexus:
    image: sonatype/nexus3:3.41.1
    container_name: nexus3
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
      - 5000:5000
```

After the container status was OK, I have created a `docker-hosted` repository using Nexus UI.

[image: Docker Hosted Repository Config]

After the above step, I created a new user with the following configurations:

[image: Create new user for Docker Hosted Repository]

The problem is that whenever I want to login to the local private docker repository using the `docker login localhost:5000` command and pass the username and password of the created user, I face to the following error:

```
docker login localhost:5000                                                                                                                                                                   
Username: nexus
Password: nexus
Error response from daemon: login attempt to http://localhost:5000/v2/ failed with status: 401 Unauthorized
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of login authentication was solved after adding **Docker bearer token** to active realms.

[image: Active Realms]